# How to interpret BusyBox top command output for load average?

Tags: busybox, top-command

I've got an embedded device that runs BusyBox v1.16.1, and its *top* command includes the following Load average output:

```
Load average: 0.00 0.00 0.00 1/304 9357
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on what the last two values represent, e.g. "1/304" and "9357".  Can anyone explain these values?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from top.c, line 39 (from busybox snapshot), there's a mention of /proc/loadavg

```
cp /proc/stat /proc/meminfo /proc/loadavg .
```

On my system right now, I see:

```
0.11 0.23 0.27 1/564 21830
```

[RedHat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-loadavg.html) explains it like this:

> The first three columns measure CPU and IO utilization of the last
>   one, five, and 10 minute periods. The fourth column shows the number
>   of currently running processes and the total number of processes. The
>   last column displays the last process ID used.

Comment: I was looking at *top* documentation, and should have been looking for *load average*!  Thanks.